# Copy exact contents of a cell in Excel with formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to copy cell O80 into cell O86, and have it appear in O86 exactly as it is in O80, with the new lines.

The text in O80 is

```
'1

2

3
```

and the formula in O86 is

```
=O80
```

Here is an image for reference:
[image: Here is an image for reference]

I am guessing there must be a formula to achieve this, like `=EXACTTEXT(O80)` or something like that (obviously this is not a real formula).

Thanks!

Comment: Do the cells have different formating?

Comment: no, same formatting

Comment: Is wrap text on for O86?

Comment: That's fixed it! There was no text wrap on O86, but when I turned it on, it was displayed correctly. Interestingly, there is no text wrap on O80, but it still appears correctly